# About Lifecycle, And how to call `on_deactivate()` in `hardware_interface` of ros2_control by controller_manager CLI or other method?

Tags: controller-manager, ros2-control

I have implemented a hardware interface in ros2_control and added code to free my hardware resources in the `on_deactivate()` method.

When I try to stop the controller with the command `ros2 control set_controller_state diffbot_base_controller inactive` and try to free the hardware, `on_deactivate()` doesn't seem to be called.

I can't find console output from `deactivate`, and the read/write method is still being called. Unlike before, only the value from hw_command_ is 0.

It's very confusing.Maybe I'm confused about the life cycle concept in `controller_manager` of ros2_control. I was hoping to get some tips or links to relevant materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that hardware components and controllers are different parts of ros2_control. You try to deactivate the controller -> this does not deactivate the hardware component.

Lifecycle of hardware components is not 100% implemented as by now, and there [are some issues](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/1103) with the current implementation. Moreover, controller won't be deactivated currently if you deactivate the hardware_component, where the controller claimed the interfaces.

Have a look at [this draft example](https://github.com/StoglRobotics-forks/ros2_control_demos/pull/7), which should make things more clear.

Comment: I found the description about lifecycle of hardware on the site: [Controller Manager — ROS2\_Control: Humble Oct 2023 documentation](https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/ros2_control/controller_manager/doc/userdoc.html#restarting-hardware). And it seems like there are no way to invoke the method  `on_deactivate()` of hareware yet.

Comment: no, the disclaimer of not being implemented is the automatic restart incl. controllers after returning false from read/write method of the hardware component. have you tried the service calls from the demo I linked above?

Comment: It works! Thanks, I learned how to control the hardware lifecycle. But I'm confused about read/write methods: methods are still called when the hardware is inactive.

Comment: the design draft is to be not able to control joints but secondary stuff like gpio commands etc also in inactive state.